# AES/CBC encryption difference between C and C# implementations

Tags: c#, c, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm attempting to write C# implementation for AES CBC encryption of messages. The goal is to "properly" encrypt a message in C# so that the C implementation could properly decrypt it.

The C decryption implementation looks like the following (using openssl):

```
/* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) {
        handleErrors();
    }

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, (unsigned char*)key, (unsigned char*)iv)) {
              handleErrors();
    }

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, (unsigned char*)plaintext, &len, (unsigned char*)encrypted_text, encrypted_text_len)) {
        handleErrors();
    }
    plaintext_len = len;

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, (unsigned char*)plaintext + len, &len)) {
        //Error happens here...
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
error: digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:518:
```

C# code:

```
static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }       
            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }
```

I have tried all of the padding modes, no luck. Any ideas of what the issue could be?

Comment: You're working here with `char[]` and `byte[]`. How exactly are you transporting the ciphertext from one to the other? Keep in mind that you cannot copy and paste binary data.

Comment: Also try, immediately following swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
add swEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

Comment: For testing purposes, simply dumping bytes to a file in C#, and reading them in C.

Comment: Flushing it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The message gets partially decrypted, but the final call fails. Although I can't pin point as to why the final block length is different.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `encrypted_text_len % 16 != 0`.

You should double check that you aren't getting an accidental newline into your buffer if you're reading from a file.